# Insert and update the record with Auto Increment ID

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get auto increment ID from the last query and update the same row. Also I would like to keep everything in the transaction and throw user friendly error if something goes wrong. Could you please help?

```
    $parentSQL = "INSERT INTO TABLE1(test1, test2) VALUES ('" .$test1. "', '" .$test2. "')";
$result = mysql_query($parentSQL) or die(mysql_error());

$newId = MySql_Insert_Id();

$val = "MU".$newId;

$updateSQL = "UPDATE TABLE1 SET test3 = '" .$val. "' WHERE id= ".$newId." ";

$updateResult = mysql_query($updateSQL) or die(mysql_error());

$childSQL = "INSERT INTO TABLE2(testId, testCol) VALUES (" .$newId. ", '" .$testCol. "')";

$childResult = mysql_query($childSQL) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Help with what? what is your problem?

Comment: I just to want make sure whether I am doing right. Also Is there any better way doing this with Transaction. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: what sort of storage engine you are using? The column test3 is redundant anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a suggestion, but why don't you try using stored procedures instead?

In MySQL

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test (
    IN param1 VARCHAR(20)
    , IN param2 VARCHAR(20)
    , IN param3 VARCHAR(20)
    , IN param4 VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLE1(test1, test2) VALUES (param1, param2);

    UPDATE TABLE1 SET test3 = CONCAT(param3, LAST_INSERT_ID());

    INSERT INTO TABLE2(testId, testCol) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), param4);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

In PHP, and using *[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)* to utilize prepared statements:

```
$q = $db->prepare("CALL test (?,?,?,?)");
$q->bindParam(1, $test1);
$q->bindParam(2, $test2);
$q->bindParam(3, $val);
$q->bindParam(4, $testCol);
$q->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to have your queries in a transaction ? If yes, just put your queries calls between :

```
mysql_query('START TRANSACTION');

// your queries

mysql_query('COMMIT');
```

Not sure I completely understood what your problem really is.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/commit.html